# Can Extendscript ActionManager script get bits per channel and color mode from layer?

Tags: jsx, photoshop, extendscript

Can Adobe ActionManager script get bits per channel and color mode from layer?  **Without using DOM** as it is not accessible from within the routines.  In Extendscript I need to derive the bits per channel (8, 16, or 32) and the color mode (RGB, LAB, CMYK, ...) from a layer within Photoshop?  Also needed are the number of channels, if the layer is a background layer, what are the ruler Units(px, mm, in).  I don't think I need to reset any of them but routines assume 8 bit-RGB-3 channels.

What codes if any are available in ActionManager to handle this?

Thanks,
RONC

Comment: Want do you mean, from layer? Those are document properties

Comment: Those are also layer properties.  RONC

Comment: I am not super familiar with ActionManager, but I found this post in the adobe forums which seems to offer relevant guidance for getting some of these property values:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/action-manager-scripting/td-p/11160326?page=1